# Karma and Jasmine vuejs2 Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have the following test spec.js

```
'use strict';
 import ContactForm from '../../../js/components/Contact/ContactForm.vue' 
describe('Contact Form', () => {
  it('Should have data property', () => {
    expect(typeof ContactForm.data).toBe('function')
})
});
```

But am now getting an error

```
 {
"message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier",
"str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"
}
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Hello Geoffrey, have you been able to find a solution to this problem? I am experiencing it myself and don't have any clue to fixing it.

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the default version of jasmine packages installed. Downgrading to 2.99 of jasmine and jasmine-core has fixed the issue. See https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-unit-testing-example/issues/79